# How to access user control page dropdownlist control id from main page's javascript function?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

**main page :**

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="A" TagName="AA" Src="~/UserControls/ab.ascx" %>

 <A:AA id="a1" runtat="server" />
 <asp:Button ID="btn" Visible="true" runat="Server" OnClick="Btn_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:PreLoad();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function PreLoad() {
 var empty = '<%= (a1.FindControl("ddl")).ClientID %>'; 
// the above line giving error as 'ddl is inaccessible due to its protection level'
}
</script>
```

**in Usercontrol page:**

```
 <%@ ControlLanguage="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ab.ascx.cs" inherits="ab.ascx.designer.cs" %>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

**in ab.ascx.designer.cs**

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList ddl;
```

Someone please explain the clean and simple proper way to access the 'ddl' inside the 'PreLoad()'
javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your tag to:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

This means that the control is rendered using the exact ID that you specified.
Then change your javascript to use the exact id of the control and access it by:

```
document.getElementById("ddl");
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$("#ddl");
```

Ideally you should move this javascript code to an external file too.

Comment: Thanks, it is really working, would you mind to shed some light on how this is working by that 'ClientIDMode="static" ?  is there any other side affects by this 'static' ?

Comment: Webforms gives all controls it adds to the page a unique client id. This is the value that gets put into the raw html. You can get it by calling .ClientID, like you have in your code. using ClientIDMode="static" means that the client id is set to whatever you specify, rather than letting webforms generate it. The benefit is, you can access it from anywhere in your javascript, like above. The only slight downside is it makes room for the developer to make mistakes. You can potentially add 2 controls with the same ID if you are not careful.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, could you pls explain why my ClientID approach didn't work?

Comment: I think your only problem is the spelling mistake of "runat", you have "runtat". So a1 isnt added to the designer. But if you were asking for a "proper" way, I think you should put your javascript in an external file. And to do that, you need static IDs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure in my actual code no mistake of 'runtat', still got the error of 'ddl is inaccessible due to its protection level' . Is this correct ? var empty = '<%= (a1.FindControl("ddl")).ClientID %>';

Comment: (a1.FindControl("ddl")).ClientID works for me when i have runtat changed to runat. But again, you should probably put your javascript event handlers into an external file, rather than embedding them in the markup and using "OnClientClick".